# How to undo vgchange --clustered y?

Tags: linux, lvm, cluster, lvm2

At the beginning of a cluster setup I invoked `sudo vgchange --clustered y [name]` and accepted the warning that the volume might be inaccessible - no problem, of course, because the cluster isn't setup up yet and the fact that it's inaccessible from other cluster nodes seemed natural. Yet, LVM developers confused "inaccessible" means with a pointful term like "destroyed"/"unmountable" for the actual consequence of the command. `sudo vgchange --clustered n [name]` fails with `Skipping clustered volume [name]`. There's no cluster configuration at all except `locking_type` changed from `1` to `3`. Changing back doesn't help. How to make the volume group and the logical volume on it "accessible" again?

I'm using lvm2 on Ubuntu 15.10 with Linux 4.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should not be used if there's a cluster running and the `vgchange --clustered y` wasn't accidental in the way described in the question because you risk (meta)data loss:

```
vgchange -cn $vgname --config 'global {locking_type = 0}'
```

https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-cluster/2016-March/msg00003.html